# How to get body font-size in Stylus?

Tags: css, font-size, stylus

I am using Stylus for my CSS and it works fine except one pesky thing. I am working with REM unit so I made a function to auto convert px to rem

```
pxToRem(pixels, context = $rootUnitSize)
  return unit(pixels / context, 'rem')

pxToRem(20) //it convert 20px to rem
```

It works great when I have only one unit to calculate. But I have two (or more in future). 14 px on the Web and 13px on the mobile.

```
/* main root font-size. It used for the REM calculation */
$rootUnitSize = 14px
/* this value uses on tablets */
$rootTabletUnitSize = 13px
/* this value uses on phones */
$rootSmartPhoneUnitSize = 13px
```

So when I change my html font size to lowest value I lost the correct dimensions. Because my html size - 13 , but root value for the calculation 14.

```
html
  font-size: $rootUnitSize
  +narrower-than(tablet)
    font-size: $rootTabletUnitSize  //now root unit is 13. But not for `calculations`
```

To resolve this issue I did a possibility to pass context (for ex - mobile root unit size)

```
margin-bottom: pxToRem(3, $rootSmartPhoneUnitSize)
```

But I don't like this solution, so, maybe other more elegant way exists? (something like....get font size from some tag? like HTML?)

Comment: You can also use the CSS `calc` function for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can I use it in my situation?